# How to update splash screen without must delete App from device manually in Xamarin iOS project?

Tags: ios, xamarin, splash-screen

I changed  "Images.xcassets" with images that I need with steps:

1. Clean my solution and rebuild it;
2. Delete the APP from my device if I already install the old one;
3. Then install the new one, it will works.

As you can see, Step 2 is not good for users when they update my app.
So, How to update splash screen without must delete App from device manually in Xamarin iOS project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem as below:

Step 1:
Open Images.xcassets from Resources folder in Xamarin iOS project.
Right click -> App Icons & Launch Images -> New Launch Image.

[image: Step 1]

After that you can add your images into the new splash screen.

Step 2:
Goto Infor.plist file -> Source item, you need to select the new splash screen that you created.

[image: Step 2]

Thank you! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

That won't be the case when an app is distributed via the App Store.

You only see the issue when building / installing / debugging during development.

Edit: This is common when building from Xcode as well - it's not just a Xamarin issue.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging you may try turning off "Fast Deployment". I believe this will cause the entire package to be reinstalled every time you run it in debug. I know that is an option for Android build, not sure if it applies to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

My easiest solution was to change the names of the images and the references to them. No matter what I did (even deleting the app before debugging) showed the old image. As soon as I renamed the image and changed the reference in LaunchScreen.storyboard to point to the renamed images, it showed correctly.